# site blocked by ssl when i am using com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.recaptcha.ReCaptcha in https environment

Tags: java

am facing problem with com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.recaptcha.ReCaptcha in https environment

the below one is what i am exactly facing

SSL blocks and show a message as:- your browser try to read resource unauthorised site and if i click yes it will show https:// with red line crossed

am using a annotation 
@JavaScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js")

please tell me any one what's the solution to solve this issue

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it´s pretty hard to understand..

Comment: i am host my site in aws it is https environment and in project i am using com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.recaptcha.ReCaptcha add-on of google recaptcha it requires java-script annotation there am using the following annotation @JavaScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js") when am i load my page browser block and show a message your requested site try to load resources form unauthorised site